# Why system_clock time_point can not be constructed from duration?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-chrono

Browsing cppreference shows that in theory any `time_point` should be constructible from duration.

```
constexpr explicit time_point( const duration& d );
```

> 2. Constructs a time_point at Clock's epoch plus d.

But when I try it on [some compilers it does not work, on some it works](https://godbolt.org/z/d7rs6ssKa).

Second lambda does not work, but surprisingly first one does.

Even more surprisingly it seems to depend on std lib implementation since clang with libc++ works.

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
int main() {
    [] { return steady_clock::time_point(seconds(1000'000'000) + nanoseconds(1)); };
    [] { return system_clock::time_point(seconds(1000'000'000) + nanoseconds(1)); };
}
```

note: I know the answer, but I find it interesting so I wanted to share since I found no answer to this on SO, if nobody is interested in answering I will answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The durations of `system_clock` and `steady_clock` are implementation defined. On platforms where it does not have (at least) nanosecond resolution, there isn't a constructor that takes `nanoseconds`.

If you add a `duration_cast` to an appropriate duration, then both work.

```
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;
int main() {
    [] { return steady_clock::time_point(duration_cast<steady_clock::duration>(seconds(1000'000'000) + nanoseconds(1))); };
    [] { return system_clock::time_point(duration_cast<system_clock::duration>(seconds(1000'000'000) + nanoseconds(1))); };
}
```

Comment: another option is to just use micros instead of nanos if it is acceptible(since afaik all system_clocks have > micros precision), but then obviously you are limited by micros resolution.

Comment: For learning purposes, one can say that time_points treat integral truncation in the same manner that durations do.  So once you learn durations, there's not that much more to learn about time_points.

Comment: @HowardHinnant true, but I also wish that std implementors provided a nicer error messages, seems like something that should be possible... especially since people claimed concepts make this possible...